# Insufficient Privileges in Report Folder as Admin

Tags: reporting, folder

So I am preparing to active enhanced report folder sharing and reviewing the existing folders. I run a query to grab a list of the existing reports:

```
Select Id, AccessType, DeveloperName, Name, Type From Folder
```

And I spot some folders with no name, or just a *. I grab the id and enter in the browser. Most end up as the out of the box folder but for two of the folders I receive:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary

Now if if I had one for every user I would assume their were personal folders...but there are a lot more than two users.

I have raised a case with Salesforce, but I'm intrigued has anyone experience this before?

**Edit**
Just to add, if it helps, the AccessType is "Public" for both of them in the query result.

**Update1**
I've compared in a sandbox with the *Enable access levels for sharing report and dashboard folders* turned on and the same folders return in the query but still aren't accessible. Waiting on Salesforce support to see what they can tell me about the folders now.

**Update2**
Reviewing the results of query I have a sneaky suspicion that one of them is the unfiled public report folder. If you create a report on reports and include the folder the hyperlink for the unfiled public report folder takes you to the Company Information page...

Comment: could these be folders created by salesforce to hold the administrative reports? Do you see a specific folder called Administrative reports ?

Comment: One of the * folders was called "Administrative Reports" but I could access that.

Comment: I do see some * folders too "Name":"*","AccessType":"Shared","Type":"Report", but i do have access to the folder. Did you check to see IsReadonly = true? and what do you see for the type?

Comment: Can you also check if "Enable access levels for sharing report and dashboard folders" is enabled for your org, the access level kicks in once you have the feature enabled. To compare different access levels check this doc: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=analytics_folder_access_chart.htm&language=en_US

Comment: @rao I've updated the question. No luck I'm afraid!

Comment: are you sure you are a standard sys admin/ not ona custom sys admin profile? many orgs have a sys admin clone to control access.

Comment: It's the standard sys admin profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of time with Salesforce support it appears these folders are created as part of the original Salesforce org setup but are folders specific to territory management. As we currently do not have territory management activated the folders aren't accessible through the UI but are queryable so you can tell of their existence!