# Report Folder access - Strange anomaly

Tags: reporting, folder

In the process of cleaning up our reports and ran across this strange anomaly:

There are two users in a Profile that appear to have Sys Admin "like" visibility into Report Folders as they see all of the same folders that I do (?) So it isn't a Profile setting... Something must be set somewhere that gives them this access but for the life of me I can't find it!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: This sounds similar to what I hit: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51274/insufficient-privileges-in-report-folder-as-admin

Comment: (1) find the folder in the left hand sidebar on Reports tab; (2) hover over the little folder icon, select Edit; (3) Look at folder sharing options - roles/roles and subordinates, public groups

Comment: Let me clarify the

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that... Let me clarify the issue:  I have 20 Sales guys who all have the same Profile... most in the group cannot see the folders but there are two users who can see ALL folders as if they had Sys Admin rights - This is not a case of a specific folders Sharing being set differently.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a "Permission set" that had been created with these two users that granted them System permission to "Manage Reports in Public Folders" This overrode the Folder Share settings and allowed them to have CRED rights for all Public folders.  Now I know!

Answer (score 0):

Report folder access is less influenced by profile than it is by roles. When you speak of Sales guys, I associate that you are speaking of a sales profile.

However, apart from profiles a user can be assigned a role. Depending on what role they have, they may have access to more than what other users access. You should definitely double-check if the sharing settings for folders include roles or groups where those two sales users are included, also by checking parent roles.